# Yii Framework Database Relationship

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I have a problem in defining the class relationship.

Before that, let me show you my database structure

```
    Agent table
    id
    username
    password

    Views table
    id
    agent_id
    accessor_id
```

An agent can allow a lot of agents to view their postings. The table view holds the data for agent owner and the agent that is allowed to view his/her posting.

My relation statement on view model is declared as follows:

```
/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations() {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'agents' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Agent', 'agent_id'),
    );
}
```

My relation statement on agent model is declared as follows:

```
/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations() {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'groups'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Group', 'group_id'),
        'views' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'View', 'agent_id'),
    );
}
```

I received the following error when I tried to run the application.

```
The relation "views" in active record class "Agent" is specified with an invalid foreign key "agent_id". There is no such column in the table "agents".
```

How can I solve this? Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

agent->views is not `BELONGS_TO` relationship. It is either `HAS_ONE` or `HAS_MANY`:

```
'views' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'View', 'agent_id'),
```

Comment: But I am unable to display data with the following:

    <?php foreach ($agents as $i => $obj) { print_r( $obj->views ); } ?>

Comment: What do you mean unable? If it's empty, probably you just haven't related data in views table.

Answer (score -2):

you should need to define relation in only view model...

```
public function relations() {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'agents' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Agent', 'agent_id'),
    );
}
```

And there is no need to define relation in agent model..

In the controller end you can find the record like this ...

```
$model = View::model()->with('agents')->findAll();
```

In this $model you have all record of view and also agent..

hope this will work for you..